# How to extract particular key from HTTP cookies in Python?

Tags: python, parsing, http, cookies, request

Trying to get a particular value from the cookie string of an HTTP request in Python.  I believe possibly using the `requests` library or `urllib2` would be a good idea.

**Example:**

Assume

```
headers['cookie'] = 'somekey=somevalue;someotherkey=someothervalue'
```

Trying to retrieve the value of `somekey`.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Cookies can be little %*$%ards. Every time I've tried to use them, there is always some tiny thing I do wrong and they don't work. Best to use a wrapper library.

Using WSGI, you can use the python "cookie" library:

```
import Cookie

# The function that receives the request
def application(environ, start_response):
    cookie = Cookie.SimpleCookie()
    cookie.load(environ['HTTP_COOKIE'])
    some_value = cookie['some_key'].value
```

Comment: Cool.  The `Cookie.SimpleCookie` seems to provide the functionality I need.  Thanks!

Comment: Note: The `Cookie` module has been renamed to `http.cookies` in Python 3 - [docs.python.org](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cookie.html)